# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am writing a program using `Python`. My program is as following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep  2 15:22:31 2020
"""

from collections import namedtuple

Customer = namedtuple('Customer', 'name fidelity')

class LineItem:
    
    def __init__(self, product, quantity, price):
        self.product = product
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price
        
    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
    
    
class Order:
    def __init__(self, customer, cart, promotion=None):
        self.customer = customer
        self.cart = list(cart)
        self.promotion = promotion
        
    def total(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '__total'):
            self.__total = sum(item.total() for item in self.cart)
            
        return self.__total
    
    def due(self):
        if self.promotion is None:
            discount = 0
        else:
            discount = self.promotion(self)
        return self.total() - discount

    def __repr__(self):
        fmt = '<Order total:{:.2f} due: {:.2f}>'
        return str(fmt.format(self.total(), self.due()))
    

def fidelity_promo(order):
    if order.customer.fidelity >= 1000:
        return order.total() * .05
    

joe = Customer('John Doe', 0)
ann = Customer('Ann Smith', 1100)
cart = [LineItem('banana', 4, .5),
        LineItem('apple', 10,1.5)]

print(Order(joe, cart, fidelity_promo))
```

However, When I run it, it always show an error:

```
  File "C:/Users/hanlulu/Desktop/Python/chapter06-285.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(Order(joe, cart, fidelity_promo))

  File "C:/Users/hanlulu/Desktop/Python/chapter06-285.py", line 46, in __repr__
    return str(fmt.format(self.total(), self.due()))

  File "C:/Users/hanlulu/Desktop/Python/chapter06-285.py", line 42, in due
    return self.total() - discount

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

How solve it?

Comment: What `if order.customer.fidelity < 1000`? Then `fidelity_promo` returns `None`…

Comment: @deceze♦  Thanks. I solve it according to your suggestion. I am new for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 38 states:

```
discount = self.promotion(self)
```

Where `self.promotion` is initialized with the function `fidelity_promo`.

Yet in that function, the if clause doesn't get in and we return `None`:

```
def fidelity_promo(order):
    # We don't get in :/
    if order.customer.fidelity >= 1000:
        return order.total() * .05
    # <-- We reach here, return None
```

We should handle both cases:

```
def fidelity_promo(order):
    if order.customer.fidelity >= 1000:
        return order.total() * .05
    return 0
```

Code Fix:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep  2 15:22:31 2020
"""

from collections import namedtuple

Customer = namedtuple('Customer', 'name fidelity')


class LineItem:

    def __init__(self, product, quantity, price):
        self.product = product
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price = price

    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity


class Order:
    def __init__(self, customer, cart, promotion=None):
        self.customer = customer
        self.cart = list(cart)
        self.promotion = promotion

    def total(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '__total'):
            self.__total = sum(item.total() for item in self.cart)

        return self.__total

    def due(self):
        if self.promotion is None:
            discount = 0
        else:
            discount = self.promotion(self)
        return self.total() - discount

    def __repr__(self):
        fmt = '<Order total:{:.2f} due: {:.2f}>'
        return str(fmt.format(self.total(), self.due()))


def fidelity_promo(order):
    if order.customer.fidelity >= 1000:
        return order.total() * .05
    return 0


joe = Customer('John Doe', 0)
ann = Customer('Ann Smith', 1100)
cart = [LineItem('banana', 4, .5),
        LineItem('apple', 10, 1.5)]

# <Order total:17.00 due: 0.00>
print(Order(joe, cart, fidelity_promo))
```